# How to read data from Greenplum via spark using filters

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark, greenplum

I am trying to filter data using a where clause having OR condition from Greenplum. I am using “Greenplum” connector in spark.

Snippet -

```
Df1 = Df.filter(col(‘id’)==‘1’ & (col(‘Name’)==‘abc’ | col(‘Name’).isNull()))
```

The connector translates this into a sql query internally and it looks like this -

```
Select * from df where
id=‘1’ and Name=‘abc’ or Name is null;
```

This is an incorrect query because I want to fetch all the records where id is 1 and name is abc or null. With this query the data fetched has records where id not equal to 1 but name is null.

Comment: This looks like an issue. We are looking into providing a fix for the next release.

Comment: Thank you @frankgh anyway we can track this?

Comment: I will post a response here when the fix is available. You can also keep an eye out to new releases in the Greenplum Spark Connector documentation page https://greenplum-spark.docs.pivotal.io/latest/GSC170ReleaseNotes.html

Comment: Hi Ankita, the new Greenplum Connector for Apache Spark (v.2.0) has been released. It fixes the issue stated above.